# Expression from one query being pulled into subsequent query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a the following tables "Base" and "Join":

```
Base:
ID  Field
A   1
B   2
D   

Join:
ID
A
B
C
D
```

I use the following select query "ExampleQuery" to parse "Base":

```
SELECT Base.ID, IIf(IsNull([Field]),"None",[Field]) AS Newfield
FROM Base;
```

And the following select query to left-join table "Join" to query "ExampleQuery":

```
SELECT Join.ID, ExampleQuery.Newfield
FROM [Join] LEFT JOIN ExampleQuery ON Join.ID = ExampleQuery.ID;
```

My output is the following:

```
ID  Newfield
A   1
B   2
C   None
D   None
```

I am expecting the value of C to be null since it was not present in the output of ExampleQuery, however it is using the logic from the expression in the original query instead. What causes this to occur, and how can I prevent it? I want to treat my initial select query strictly as a temporary table.

Comment: Please show us the queries used to generate this output.  And some sample data would be nice as well.

Comment: I have revised my initial question, hopefully this helps to clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try joining to a subquery which first replaces missing field values in the `Base` table with `None`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Newfield
FROM [Join] t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, IIF(ISNULL([Field]),"None", [Field]) AS Newfield
    FROM Base
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

By the way, `JOIN` is a reserved keyword in Access (and probably every other version of SQL).  You should avoid naming tables, columns, etc. using keywords.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in standard SQL but in Access I am getting the same result, the value of C is "None". And yes, poor choice of naming convention on my part.

Comment: @ChrisDecker I don't see why my query would not work.  I will setup a demo.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there are two ways the field can be null: It could be null because there is a record where that field is null, or it could be because it there is no matching record at all for the outer join to find.

It does sound like you've added another table to your query, rather than joined the entire query to a table as you've stated. I think to resolve this you would need to do what you've described, which is to outer join the entire query. In Access this can be achieved by starting with your query that returns

```
ID  NewField
A   1
B   2
D   None
```

And saving it as, e.g., Query1. You would then create a new query, and include Query1 (Access treats this just like a table), then outer join it to your other table.

Answer (score 0):

Pending actual resolution, I've found a workaround by adding another condition to the expression. If I change "ExampleQuery" to:

```
SELECT Base.ID, IIf(IsNull([Field]) And Not IsNull([ID]),"None",[Field]) AS Newfield
FROM Base;
```

Then I get my desired output when I run the subsequent query matching "ExampleQuery" to table "Join":

```
ID  Newfield
A   1
B   2
C   
D   None
```

Comment: Chris, if you want to answer your own question, you should at least post the entire query.

Comment: I didn't know if I should add this as an answer or append it to my initial question, but I just wanted to note this workaround in case anyone else experiences my same problem. You're right,sorry I just posted the expression. I will revise to show the entire query.