# Strange behavior in a SQL left join

Tags: sql, left-join, coalesce

I am posting this question in response to answer I recently wrote on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197991/expression-from-one-query-being-pulled-into-subsequent-query/48198231?noredirect=1#comment83377678_48198231).  The question involves two tables:

```
Base:
ID  Field
A   1
B   2
D   NULL

Join:
ID
A
B
C
D
```

And here is the desired output:

```
Output:
ID  Newfield
A   1
B   2
C   NULL
D   None
```

In other words, we want to distinguish between missing fields due to missing values in `Base`, and those fields missing because they don't even have an `ID` appearing `Base`.  `None` means that `ID` was present in `Base` with a `NULL` field, and `NULL` means we didn't even see the `ID` in `Base` at all.  I thought that the following query (adapted to ANSI SQL) would work:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Newfield, t2.ID
FROM `Join` t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, COALESCE(Field, 'None') AS Newfield, Field
    FROM Base
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

Yet as you can see in the demo below, both the `C` and `D` IDs have `None` as the reported new field.  I would have expected `D` alone to have `None`, and `C` should be reported as `NULL`.

Can someone explain this?  To make this more strange, if I remove the `ORDER BY` clause in the above query/demo, then everything works as expected.

### Demo

Comment: This would appear to be a bug.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yup...this is my feeling.  Can you confirm that my query _should_ produce the expected results, ignoring bugs?  I ask because I don't want to post any misinformation here.

Comment: . . Even without testing the query, the addition of the `order by` should not change the *set* of rows being returned.  Period.  `order by` should only affect order, not the contents of the rows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ... can you confirm this behavior in an actual DBMS as opposed to these online demo tools?

Comment: This is a RexTester bug, plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem in Online Compiler versions.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Newfield
FROM `Join` t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, IFNULL(Field, 'None') AS Newfield, Field
    FROM Base
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

Because the 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df77a1/3) gives the exact result what we expected.

And the [Rex Tester](http://rextester.com/TYZVH46974) do some strange.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, this won't [produce the desired output](http://rextester.com/LCRS52232) because your query can't distinguish between the two types of missing values.  In any case, my question was mainly about trying to get the original query to work, not to use a workaround.

Comment: In your question the Field for Id D is empty ' ', but you insert the value as NULL, I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry, in the `Base` table `D` has a `NULL` field value, not empty string.  I see where your query is coming from now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, same queries gives the expected result in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df77a1/3 and strange in http://rextester.com/TYZVH46974.